# VMWare Fusion + VMWare for linux - sharing bootcamp partition

Tags: linux, vmware-fusion

I have a macbook pro, where I mainly run MacOSX and Linux, but I do need to run some windows-only programs. I have three boot partitions, MacOSX, Windows XP and Linux (debian/ubuntu). From within MacOSX I run the windows bootcamp partition inside VMWare Fusion.

Now the question is whether with the VMware Server or other VMWare solution I can run the same windows partition from within the linux system.

Can the bootcamp partition be runned within any (non-Fusion) vmware solution while it has the fusion drivers installed?

Answer (score 1):

I've done this, sort of.  I installed Windows XP via VMWare Workstation under Linux on a raw partition, then booted into it.  If you set some magic registry key (search for "windows xp moving hard drive to new computer" or something) that tells it to look for new hardware on boot, it works *ok*.  There will be some mystery drivers that don't work (the ones that work in VMWare), but you'll be ok.

With a second hardware configuration in Windows, you'll be ok.

I don't know how VMWare Fusion or Bootcamp will play with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the Windows Partition as a VM within Linux like you can in the MacOS with VMware Fusion or Parallels by running VMware Workstation inside your Linux distro.